Using PEBS/PMU in QEMU to sample exact addr of memory operation
I'm trying to use PEBS/PMU in QEMU to sample exact addr of memory operation, I met a similar problem which is mentioned 3 years ago in this link and I quote the text part below.

I tried to use perf_event_open() to track all the store instructions to get their access address. I found only when I set attr.precise_ip > 0, I can get the non-zero address. But when I ran the same process on vm instead of host, the error massage was "Operation not supported", I can fix this problem by setting precise_ip = 0 on vm, but now I only get bunch of addresses equal to zero. I don't understand why precise_ip is related to the sample addrress which is not pointed out on document, and I also don't understand why I can't set precise_ip = 1 on vm while I can do it on host. Is there anybody can help me??

I have conducted further checks.
When I run QEMU with the -cpu host option, the kernel log of the guest OS mentions "Performance Events: Skylake events, Intel PMU driver," which seems normal for startup.
However, I noticed that in the host OS, the output of lscpu includes both the arch_perfmon and pebs flags, while in the guest OS, only arch_perfmon is present, and pebs is missing. I'm unsure how to enable this support.
Based on Intel's documentation, I tried running cpuid | grep -A 1 Architecture Performance Monitoring Features (0xa/eax) and found that the version ID in the host OS is 4, while in the guest OS, it is 2. This indicates different levels of support, but I'm not sure how to modify this.
I also came across a patch that mentioned the following:

Bug #2 is that, because KVM always sets precise_ip to a non-zero value
for PEBS events, perf will always generate an adaptive record, even if
the guest requested a basic record.  Note, KVM will also enable adaptive
PEBS in individual counter, even if adaptive PEBS isn't exposed to the
guest, but this is benign as MSR_PEBS_DATA_CFG is guaranteed to be zero,
i.e. the guest will only ever see Basic records.


Re:The three issues above all point to a fix in one direction: to pass the value
of vcpu's EVT_SELx.Adaptive_Record[34] or FCx_Adaptive_Record to the
perf/core in a way and let the PEBS assist take effect as expected by vPEBS. One place to address this is in the intel_guest_get_msrs() again:
update vPMC[x].pPMC.fcctl_or_evtsel.ADAPTIVE = vPMC[x].use_adaptive
, since guest PEBS is disabled if host PEBS is enabled.

It states that ICE_LAKE should have precise_ip support by default. However, in my case, it seems to be unsupported. Could this be due to an incompatible version of KVM/QEMU (how can I upgrade? Apt indicates that I already have the latest version), or is it because my CPU model is too old or too (Intel Xeon Gold 5218)?
I hope there has been progress on this issue since the previous issue was raised three years ago
